# Difference between "immergo" and "summergo"

Tags: verbs, meaning, spanish, differences

In Spanish we have the verb *sumergir*, coming from Latin:

> **[sum-mergo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=summergo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) (subm-)**, si, sum, 3, v. a.,
>
> I. *to dip* or *plunge under, to sink, overwhelm, submerge, submerse*.

Nonetheless, some related word such as *inmersión* and *inmerso* come from a similar Latin verb:

> **[immergo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=immergo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) (inm-)**, si, sum, 3 (
>
> I. *perf. sync.* immersti, Plaut. Bacch. 4, 4, 26; acc. to the second conj., *inf. pres. pass.* immergeri, Col. 5, 9, 3), v. a. in-mergo, *to dip, plunge, sink*, or *stick into* any thing, *to immerse* (mostly poet. and in post-Aug. prose).

The definitions for both verbs are quite similar, but only the *summergo* verb reached the Spanish language as *sumergir*. There were attempts to stablish an *inmergir* verb but the Royal Spanish Academy stated that such verb was pointless in the Spanish language.

So, we have *sumergir* but not *inmergir* and I'm trying to understand why. I see in the definition for *immergo* that that verb was mostly used in poetry. So was it a cultured word and hence less used? Was in fact the verb *summergo* most used in Latin than *immergo* with the meaning of *to dip, plunge* or *sink*?

Answer (score 2):

As you mention, Lewis and Short say that *immergō* was "mostly poet[ic] and in post-Aug[ustan] prose". Whitaker marks its frequency with a C, which means between 5 and 20 citations were found in his corpus.

On the other hand, L&S say that *submergō* was "class[ical]; most freq[uently] pass[ive]". Whitaker marks both *submergō* and *summergō* with a C, giving them separate entries, which may or may not actually mean it's more common.

It's also worth noting that English has verbs from the frequentitive forms "immerse" and "submerse", and a verb "submerge", but no *"immerge" (at least not that I've ever heard as a native speaker). This hints that *submergō*'s descendant was more popular in the Norman French that affected English.

From this, I'd take away that *submergō* was the common classical form, while *immergō* started off as a poetic word and got somewhat more popular later on. *Submergō* was always more common, and is the form that got better-established in Spanish and English, while *immergō* remained rarer; however, both have descendants in many Romance languages, so one never fully displaced the other.

(P.S. As a linguist, I wouldn't trust the Spanish Academy to determine what's a "real word" and what isn't. Mitomino's answer points out that *inmerger* was used by Benito Pérez Galdós, a novelist often compared to Dickens and Tolstoy, and Santiago Ramón y Cajal, a Nobel prize winner. I'd take their testimony as native speakers over the Academy's prescription any day. It might be archaic or outdated, but it seems to be a real word.)

Comment: Just a further remark on something you point out in your PS. As a linguist, I agree with you on the irrelevance of academies in theoretical linguistic matters. In fact, the linguistically interesting question is not what a "real word" is but rather what a "(im)possible word" is. E.g., cf. the lexical-syntactic decomposition view (Hale & Keyser) and the atomist view (Fodor & colleagues).

Answer (score 1):

Both verbs do exist in Catalan: *immergir* and *submergir* (vid. https://dlc.iec.cat/). *Immergir*: "ficar **dins** un líquid" ('to introduce **into** a liquid') / *Submergir*: "Posar **sota** l’aigua o altre líquid" ('to put **under** the water or other liquid").

As for Spanish, I've seen that *inmergir* is found in authors like Ramón y Cajal o Pérez Galdós. Vid. https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/648450561776427008 According to RAE (*Real Academia Española*), "[su uso] sería raro, pero perfectamente correcto" ('[its use] would be odd, but perfectly correct'). So feel free to use both verbs!